# ReactJs how to access to DOM element

Tags: reactjs, dom, global-variables, element

I have a problem, 
I would like to access to a DOM Element with a global variable for using it in all my methods, 
I tried to access it with "this.refs" but it seems to be only for forms and input ?
Maybe you know a better way to do it ?
Here is some of my code :

`
    import React from 'react';

```
var isSmall = false;
var isMedium = false;
var isLarge = true;
```

class App extends React.Component {

```
openIframe()
{

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    var siteUrl = document.getElementById('siteUrl').value;
    var header = document.getElementById('header');

    iframe.src = "";
    iframe.src = siteUrl;
    iframe.setAttribute('id', 'iframe');
    header.classList.add('scrollUp');

    setTimeout( function (){
        document.getElementById("iframe_append").appendChild(iframe);
    },500);
}

reloadIframe ()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe.src = iframe.src;
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use ref callback on HTML elements and set local variable of that component.

   input type="file" id="file" ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}

and to use it inside component call

```
this.textInput.focus();
```

2. For functional components you can use refs

   input type="file" id="file" ref="uploader"

and to use it inside component call

```
this.refs.uploader.focus();
```

Details: [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use ref callbacks for both React components and **any** DOM element. Here is a reference:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom

2) You should avoid global variables. Instead, you can export variable using ES6 modules syntax and access in any other file by importing it. For example:

App.js

```
export const someVar = 'valueOfSomeVar';
```

someOtherFile.js

```
import { someVar } from 'pathToApp.js';
console.log(someVar); // 'valueOfSomeVar'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to access DOM in React instead you can make component and place it in your components hierarchy in your desired place.